# Create a fixed-length FIFO out of an Array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need a FIFO list of a fixed size that can be set arbitrarily on object creation. An array works, but I'm tired of checking its size and popping off the oldest element every time I push a new value. I know people have said that subclassing Array is a bad idea, but I still want to do it as it's the most elegant solution to my need.

Here's my code so far.

```
class FIFOList < Array
  attr_reader :FIFO_length
  attr_writer :FIFO_length

  def initialize(l)
    super()
    @FIFO_length = l
  end

  def push(element)
    super(element)
    self.shift if self.length > @FIFO_length

end
```

With this object, I can define a 25 element FIFO like so:

```
a = FIFOList.new(25)
```

and push elements on it all day long and always have the most recent 25. As long as I'm pushing elements on one at a time (a.push()), all is good. However, I'd like to be able to initialize a new FIFO with an array, just like one can with a native Array object.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Which yields an array a, of 5 elements. But that's not how it's working and I'm not sure what to do about it. Here's an IRB session showing the problem:

```
irb(main):008:0* a = FIFOList.new(5)
=> []
irb(main):009:0> a.class
=> FIFOList
irb(main):010:0> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):011:0> a.class
=> Array
```

So instead of the static array getting assigned as the "content" of the FIFOList object, "a" simply becomes a reference to the new static array. That's not the behavior I want. From what reading I've done it seems like maybe I need to add methods to my FIFOList class to override [] and possibly []=, but I'm not sure how to do that. If that's not the right approach, I'd be happy with a "load" method that takes an array as a parameter and does the magic internally, but I'm not sure how to "load" the passed values into the self. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

You already came up with your own solution, but here's mine:

```
class FIFOList < Array
  attr_reader :fifo_length

  def initialize(len, arr=[])
    arr = arr[-len, len] if arr.size > len
    super(arr)
    @fifo_length = len
  end

  def push(*args)
    if args.size > fifo_length
      return replace(args[-fifo_length, fifo_length])
    end

    num_to_shift = (size + args.size) - fifo_length
    shift(num_to_shift) unless num_to_shift < 0
    super(*args)
  end
end

a = FIFOList.new(5, ["a1", "a2", "a3"])
p a # => ["a1", "a2", "a3"]

p a.push("b1") # => ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1"]
p a.push("c1", "c2", "c3") # => ["a3", "b1", "c1", "c2", "c3"]
p a.push("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7") # =>  ["d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7"]
```

Note that the constructor will automatically cut the initial array if it's too long, and `FIFOList#push` mirrors `Array#push` in that it takes any number of arguments and always returns `self` (and works correctly even if given too many arguments).

Though some would object to monkey-patching Array, you could also add an `Array#to_fifo` convenience method that creates a FIFOList:

```
class Array
  def to_fifo
    FIFOList.new(size, self)
  end
end

a = [1,2,3,4,5].to_fifo
p a.class # => FIFOList
```

You can see it working on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/WillingJoyfulAttributes

Comment: I like this solution the best. It's what I had in mind all along... just didn't command the nuances of the language well enough to figure it out on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do something very similar without inheriting from `Array`, but using **composition** instead:

```
class FIFOList
  attr_reader :size, :arr

  def self.[](*values)
    obj = self.new(values.size)
    obj.arr = values
    obj
  end

  def initialize(size)
    @size = size
    @arr  = Array.new
  end

  def push(element)
    arr.push(element)
    arr.shift if arr.length > size
    arr
  end
end
```

Then you can use it in a similar way:

```
a = FIFOList.new(3)
# => #<FIFOList:0x00007ffe87071150 @size=3, @arr=[nil, nil, nil]>
a.push 1
# => [nil, nil, 1]
a.push 2
# => [nil, 1, 2]
a.push 3
# => [1, 2, 3]
a.push 4
# => [2, 3, 4]
a.arr
# => [2, 3, 4]
```

Or if you want to use it without using `push` for each value:

```
a = FIFOList[1,2,3]
# => #<FIFOList:0x00007feea9015d70 @size=3, @arr=[1, 2, 3]>
a.push 4
# => [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I have edited the answer to add a `self` method that does the trick of initializing with an array.

Answer (score 1):

You probably looking for [Array#replace](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-replace) method.

> Replaces the contents of self with the contents of other_ary, truncating or expanding if necessary.

```
a = FIFOList.new(5)
a.push(10) # now the content is [10]
a.replace([1,2,3,4,5]) # => now the content is [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Indeed. that would work. Thank you. I also figured out how to pass in an optional array on initialization. Will add that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I still wish I could do straight assignment and have it work, but this code does allow me to optionally initialize.

```
class FIFOList < Array
  attr_reader :FIFO_length
  attr_writer :FIFO_length

  def initialize(l, init_value = nil)
    if init_value != nil && init_value.class.to_s == "Array" && init_value.length <= l then
      super(init_value)
      @FIFO_length = l
    elsif init_value == nil
      super()
      @FIFO_length = l
    else
      raise "optional 2nd parameter required to be an Array"
    end
  end

  def push(element)
    super(element)
    self.shift if self.length > @FIFO_length #truncate the FIFO to the defined length
  end

end
```

Comment: That's not going to do what you think it is. Calling super with the length is going to populate the array with `l * nil` So your if length check will always be true, and you will initially shift nils

Comment: Also, remove the reader and writers as they are redundant as are the calls to `self`. The instance variable should be `@fifo_length` as we do not capitalize instance variables in Ruby as a style.

Comment: `init_value.class.to_s == "Array"` is not idiomatic Ruby. `init_value.is_a?(Array)` would be more idiomatic, although duck typing is preferable to explicit type checking,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will incorporate them. As is obvious, I don't do Ruby every day ;-).